# Update a column in table which updates the same column in another table

Tags: python, mysql

I have these tables:

```
library(`SL.NO`.`STUDENT ID`,`BOOK`,`DATE`)    
books(`sl.no`,`title`,`authors`,`subject`,`availability`)

student(`STUDENT ID`,`STUDENT NAME`)
```

What I am trying is to have values inserted into table library only and I want the 'availability' column in books to update accordingly.

For example , if i add value('1','001815','Programming','date') I want the availability column for book named programing in table books to turn from yes to no.

Is there a way to do this.

My first guess was to use foreign keys and all but it is not related to column 'availability' i guess so maybe use a lil bit of python or is there way to do it mysql itself. Please help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: check out `sqlalchemy`

Comment: why won't you do two separate queries sequentially?

Comment: like one after the other in two different queries?

Comment: sqlalchemy seems so complicated :((

Comment: Have you heard of triggers?

Comment: Generally it's not great practice to store derived data. And including periods in table/column identifiers is an extremely poor idea.

Comment: sqlalchemy seems complicated in the beginning but once you get easy with it, there's nothing better than that.

Answer (score 0):

By using trigger you can do this. Whenever A table's column update then update the relative B table's column.

Comment: oh is der a operator for it?

Comment: yes it's one of the concept to handle events on table. Please refere https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-trigger link.

Comment: but also when the person returns the book i want to change the availablity into yes and when he takes book availablity into no